# How to Update collection in mongoDb using MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb

- I have 2 APIs, API 1 `router.post('/create-product')`, will **POST** data.
- API 2 `router.post('/insert-image/id')` will add files to previously added product.

  Now instead of posting images to image collection, I want to update product collection with image data.

  So , I tried doing `PUT` operation instead of `POST` on the `insert-image` API.
  Below is my post api
  **Server Code :**
       
     `router.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req , res){
        var images = req.files;
        const filePromises = req.files.map(function(file){
          var filename = Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname;
          console.log('FileName :' + filename);
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          fs.rename(file.path,'public/images/'+ filename, function(err) {
              if (err) return reject(err);
              return resolve(filename);
            });
          });
      });
      Promise.all(filePromises)
        .then( fileNames => {
          var image = new Image({
            productId: req.body.proId,
            imagePaths: fileNames
          });
          image.save(function(err, result){
            if(err) throw err;
            res.json(result);
          });
        })
      });`

  So, I am confused what all changes needs to be done. to convert this API from POST to put.

  Please help.

Comment: Maybe use `router.put()` instead of `router.post()` for a start ?

Comment: Hmm, done, what's next?

Comment: Hmm, retrieve product from db to add image information ?

Comment: yes, the moment I post product to db, i will get product id from the mongodb, with that same id I want to update same product collection with image paths.